# Disable Postfix Open Relay

Tags: postfix, smtp

For the past few weeks someone has been using my server/postfix as a relay mail server. I tried everything that was posted in the hundred of other posts on this topics, but they are able to do it again and again. I'm not sure what I've misconfigured. I tried multiple sites that test your server for open relays, and they also say I've closed all loopholes, but these people still get mails through.

Here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination


smtpd_tls_cert_file=/var/www/mydomain.com/ssl/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/var/www/mydomain.com/ssl/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

#Enabling SMTP for authenticated users, and handing off authentication to Dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unlisted_recipient
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_pipelining

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        reject_sender_login_mismatch,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unlisted_sender,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unauth_pipelining

smtp_host_lookup = native

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
```

I want only accounts from my own domain to send emails. All other sending and relaying not authenticated by one of my accounts should be blocked. Does anyone have an idea?

And here is a snippet from my mail.log containing some of the spam emails sent through my server

```
Jun 24 12:32:33 mydomain postfix/anvil[7463]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:200.60.36.35) at Jun 24 12:29:12
Jun 24 12:32:33 mydomain postfix/anvil[7463]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:200.60.36.35) at Jun 24 12:29:12
Jun 24 12:32:33 mydomain postfix/anvil[7463]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun 24 12:29:12
Jun 24 12:32:34 mydomain postfix/smtpd[7684]: connect from unknown[37.49.224.134]
Jun 24 12:32:34 mydomain postfix/smtpd[7684]: disconnect from unknown[37.49.224.134] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Jun 24 12:35:14 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8020]: connect from unknown[201.187.101.222]
Jun 24 12:35:15 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8020]: disconnect from unknown[201.187.101.222] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Jun 24 12:38:35 mydomain postfix/anvil[7686]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:37.49.224.134) at Jun 24 12:32:34
Jun 24 12:38:35 mydomain postfix/anvil[7686]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:37.49.224.134) at Jun 24 12:32:34
Jun 24 12:38:35 mydomain postfix/anvil[7686]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun 24 12:32:34
Jun 24 12:40:59 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8289]: connect from fa137.63.fix-addr.vsi.ru[80.82.63.137]
Jun 24 12:40:59 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8289]: disconnect from fa137.63.fix-addr.vsi.ru[80.82.63.137] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Jun 24 12:44:19 mydomain postfix/anvil[8291]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:80.82.63.137) at Jun 24 12:40:59
Jun 24 12:44:19 mydomain postfix/anvil[8291]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:80.82.63.137) at Jun 24 12:40:59
Jun 24 12:44:19 mydomain postfix/anvil[8291]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun 24 12:40:59
Jun 24 12:46:14 mydomain postfix/pickup[4558]: 2B8C71321632: uid=0 from=<root>
Jun 24 12:46:14 mydomain postfix/cleanup[8529]: 2B8C71321632: message-id=<20180624124614.2B8C71321632@mydomain.com>
Jun 24 12:46:14 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15111]: 2B8C71321632: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=590, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 24 12:46:14 mydomain postfix/trivial-rewrite[8530]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains
Jun 24 12:46:14 mydomain postfix/lmtp[8531]: 2B8C71321632: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=mydomain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.1, delays=0.05/0.01/0.03/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <root@mydomain.com> bTFmD5aSL1tUIQAARIBmVg Saved)
Jun 24 12:46:14 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15111]: 2B8C71321632: removed
Jun 24 12:46:37 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8548]: connect from unknown[82.214.127.122]
Jun 24 12:46:37 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8548]: disconnect from unknown[82.214.127.122] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Jun 24 12:49:57 mydomain postfix/anvil[8550]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:82.214.127.122) at Jun 24 12:46:37
Jun 24 12:49:57 mydomain postfix/anvil[8550]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:82.214.127.122) at Jun 24 12:46:37
Jun 24 12:49:57 mydomain postfix/anvil[8550]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun 24 12:46:37
Jun 24 12:52:45 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8782]: warning: hostname static-181-143-57-98.une.net.co does not resolve to address 181.143.57.98: Name or service not known
Jun 24 12:52:45 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8782]: connect from unknown[181.143.57.98]
Jun 24 12:52:45 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8782]: disconnect from unknown[181.143.57.98] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Jun 24 12:56:05 mydomain postfix/anvil[8784]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:181.143.57.98) at Jun 24 12:52:45
Jun 24 12:56:05 mydomain postfix/anvil[8784]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:181.143.57.98) at Jun 24 12:52:45
Jun 24 12:56:05 mydomain postfix/anvil[8784]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun 24 12:52:45
Jun 24 12:57:22 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8984]: connect from unknown[37.49.224.134]
Jun 24 12:57:22 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8984]: disconnect from unknown[37.49.224.134] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Jun 24 12:58:33 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8984]: connect from unknown[184.71.152.86]
Jun 24 12:58:33 mydomain postfix/smtpd[8984]: disconnect from unknown[184.71.152.86] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Jun 24 13:01:13 mydomain postfix/pickup[8799]: E32A71321633: uid=0 from=<root>
Jun 24 13:01:13 mydomain postfix/cleanup[9206]: E32A71321633: message-id=<20180624130113.E32A71321633@mydomain.com>
Jun 24 13:01:13 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15111]: E32A71321633: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=590, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 24 13:01:13 mydomain postfix/trivial-rewrite[9207]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains
Jun 24 13:01:14 mydomain postfix/lmtp[9208]: E32A71321633: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=mydomain.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.12, delays=0.07/0.01/0.03/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <root@mydomain.com> doqtARqWL1v5IwAARIBmVg Saved)
Jun 24 13:01:14 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15111]: E32A71321633: removed
```

I've done an open relay test through AppRiver. Most test said that the server was protected against open relays, but a few tests failed:

```
Test #1
S: RSET
R: 250 2.0.0 Ok
S: MAIL FROM: <spamtest@appriver.com>
R: 250 2.1.0 Ok
S: RCPT TO: <relaytest@appriver.com>
R: 250 2.1.5 Ok
Relay Accepted

Test #3
S: RSET
R: 250 2.0.0 Ok
S: MAIL FROM: <>
R: 250 2.1.0 Ok
S: RCPT TO: <relaytest@appriver.com>
R: 250 2.1.5 Ok
Relay Accepted

Test #8
S: RSET
R: 250 2.0.0 Ok
S: MAIL FROM: <spamtest@appriver.com>
R: 250 2.1.0 Ok
S: RCPT TO: <relaytest%appriver.com@[88.201.58.183]>
R: 250 2.1.5 Ok
Relay Accepted
```

Comment: The mail in the log is showing to root@mydomain.com. Where do you see outgoing mail from unauthorized connections. Did they successfully auth? Use mxtoolbox to verify for open relay.

Comment: @Gmck I added some of the test cases that failed from AppRiver (mxtoolbox does not give enough debug info). Any suggestions to get rid of this? I've done various things which blocks the relay, but then my server ends up not being able to receive any non-spam emails. Can't get it right to block all unwanted relays, but still accept valid emails.

Comment: You have permit_mynetworks & permit_sasl_authenticated. Have you checked that no user account password have been compromised? This is very common when somebody uses a weak password, or something silly such as "123456" (which should not be accepted as a password in the first place, but some systems are still allowing it). I would eliminate this as a possibility. Did you test your external IP to see if it's an open relay? Where and what was the result?

Comment: My password is complex enough, doubt that anyone would have brute-forced it. And I also keep it safe and encrypted. Yes, I did test my IP for open relays. The output is given in my edited post above. So yes, a few of the test cases do indicate my server is an open relay, I'm just not sure what to do about it, since I've disabled everything I can think of.

Comment: Can you give me the IP so I can test it?

Comment: Yes it is, see the AppRiver test case #1, #3, and #8 above.

Comment: @goocreations your log extract doesn't seem to show anything out of the ordinary, the only mail handled is to and from root. There are some clients attempting to authenticate but failing, which is normal background noise for an SMTP server.

Comment: @Gmck I don't want to plaster my IP here, since it is an open relay, and that would be advertising my server for further abuse. Any way one can send a private msg?

Comment: @TorinCarey Those emails listed in the log are not from me. Someone adds about 30000 of those emails to mail mail queue every day. So they might not look out of the ordinary, but they are not mine. My server becomes extremely slow, almost all my memory is used due to the mailing queue filling up.

Comment: I suggest looking at `http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html`. Look under "Dangerous use of smtpd_recipient_restrictions"

Comment: @goocreations the root to root ones are usually caused by local services, e.g. cron.

Answer (score -1):

I would start with fixing:

Jun 24 13:01:13 mydomain postfix/trivial-rewrite[9207]: warning: do not list domain mydomain.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains

And the setting "myhostname = mydomain.com" does not seem correct either; in that mail being sent from localhost will look like mail being relayed or received.

Comment: I don't have the relay_domains attribute defined, so not sure why it gives that warning.